# Avoiding Localization for Blog and Youtube

Tags: seo, local-seo, internationalization, international, localization

I have a blog and website that produces content for the web, and not for any region.

I have a tutorials niche that where I show how to cook recipes from all around the world.

What I want to ask is, I have the location in my webmaster's tools for my site set to that of my country. Also, when I upload videos to YouTube, I set the video location that of my country.

As a result in the analytics, I see a lot of traffic just from my country only.

What I want to ask Is how can I target the web and not just a particular country?

Do I just leave the location field empty?

Comment: *Do I just leave the location field empty?* That is certainly something to try.

Comment: Yes, I did try that but did not see any difference. There must be some definite answer. I know there is a lot of secrecy in SEO, but this must be documented somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target a worldwide audience you need two things:

1. A site on a global top level domain such as `.com`.   If you build a site on most country code domains (like `.co.uk`) then Google will only show the content to people searching in that country.
2. Not set the country for the site in Google Search Console

It sounds like you already are using a global top level domain or Google wouldn't even give you the option for setting the country in Search Console.   You just need to leave that field empty in Search Console  and on YouTube.